# Generating pdf-latex with python script

Tags: python, latex, pdflatex

I'm a college guy, and in my college, to present any kind of homework, it has to have a standard coverpage (with the college logo, course name, professor's name, my name and bla bla bla).

So, I have a .tex document, which generate my standard coverpages pdfs. It goes something like:

```
...
\begin{document}
%% College logo
\vspace{5cm}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\huge "School and Program Name" \\}
\vspace{1cm}
\textbf{\Large "Homework Title" \\}
\vspace{1cm}
\textbf{\Large "Course Name" \\}
\end{center}
\vspace{2.5cm}
\begin{flushright}
{\large "My name" }
\end{flushright}
...
```

So, I was wondering if there's a way to make a Python script that asks me for the title of my homework, the course name and the rest of the strings and use them to generate the coverpage. After that, it should compile the .tex and generate the pdf with the information given.

Any opinions, advice, snippet, library, is accepted.

Comment: Text editor is faster IMHO. You still have to input the title, course name, etc each time you print a coverpage. I'd convert that PDF to a word template. Try: http://www.pdftoword.com/

Comment: You could just use a snippet manager/template system in a text editor.

Comment: that's good idea! but I was looking for something more self made/geek.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can start by defining the template tex file as a string:

```
content = r'''\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
...
\textbf{\huge %(school)s \\}
\vspace{1cm}
\textbf{\Large %(title)s \\}
...
\end{document}
'''
```

Next, use `argparse` to accept values for the course, title, name and school:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c', '--course')
parser.add_argument('-t', '--title')
parser.add_argument('-n', '--name',) 
parser.add_argument('-s', '--school', default='My U')
```

A bit of string formatting is all it takes to stick the args into `content`:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
content%args.__dict__
```

After writing the content out to a file, cover.tex,

```
with open('cover.tex','w') as f:
    f.write(content%args.__dict__)
```

you could use `subprocess` to call `pdflatex cover.tex`.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['pdflatex', 'cover.tex'])
proc.communicate()
```

You could add an `lpr` command here too to add printing to the workflow.

Remove unneeded files:

```
os.unlink('cover.tex')
os.unlink('cover.log')
```

The script could then be called like this:

```
make_cover.py -c "Hardest Class Ever" -t "Theoretical Theory" -n Me
```

---

Putting it all together,

```
import argparse
import os
import subprocess

content = r'''\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
... P \& B 
\textbf{\huge %(school)s \\}
\vspace{1cm}
\textbf{\Large %(title)s \\}
...
\end{document}
'''

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c', '--course')
parser.add_argument('-t', '--title')
parser.add_argument('-n', '--name',) 
parser.add_argument('-s', '--school', default='My U')

args = parser.parse_args()

with open('cover.tex','w') as f:
    f.write(content%args.__dict__)

cmd = ['pdflatex', '-interaction', 'nonstopmode', 'cover.tex']
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
proc.communicate()

retcode = proc.returncode
if not retcode == 0:
    os.unlink('cover.pdf')
    raise ValueError('Error {} executing command: {}'.format(retcode, ' '.join(cmd))) 

os.unlink('cover.tex')
os.unlink('cover.log')
```

Comment: pretty good solution, and simple! now I have a automatic cover generator :)

Comment: Is there a way to check whether the pdf was generated successfully? I've found if I have an '&' or '%' in the text it breaks the pdf.

Comment: @Johan: The script shows the output of the call to `pdlatex`. If there is an error processing the LaTeX, those error messages will show you that the pdf was not successfully generated. The `&` is not a special character in Python, but it is in TeX, so you need to backslash it if you want a literal ampersand: `\&`. The `%` is a special character in both Python and TeX.  Depending on where the `%` is located, it may need to be changed to either `\%` or `%%`.

Comment: Thanks Unutbu. I actually want to run this on an remote server, so I won't be able to view the output. What I'm doing now is just checking if the pdf was generated. If it was generated, I assume everything is ok and send the pdf, if not, the server responds with an error message. Or do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: @Johan: I modified the script above to raise a ValueError if the `pdflatex`
command fails. Without `-interaction nonstopmode`, the Python process could hang
waiting for user input. Note that `pdflatex` **will still generate a pdf file even if errors occur**. You must check for the `ValueError` to know if the pdf file generated was due to a bad run.

Comment: Alternatively, you could call `os.unlink(cover.pdf)` whenever `retcode != 0`.

Comment: @unutbu how would one include a logo (/directory/somefolder/logo.jpg)?

Comment: @3kstc: Do you have the TeX code to include the logo? If you do, it should be trivial to add it to `content`. If you don't have the TeX code, start by [searching here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) for the answer.

Comment: @unutbu : thanks a lot for the answer! However, whenever I use `content%args.__dict__` I get an error message saying: 
ValueError: unsupported format character '\' (0x5c) at index 94. Do you know what it means?

Answer (score 7):

There are of course templating systems like Jinja, but they're probably overkill for what you're asking.  You can also format the page using RST and use that to generate LaTeX, but again that's probably overkill.  Heck, auto-generating the page is probably overkill for the number of fields you've got to define, but since when did overkill stop us! :)

I've done something similar with Python's string formatting.  Take your LaTeX document above and "tokenize" the file by placing `%(placeholder_name1)s` tokens into the document.  For example, where you want your class name to go, use `%(course_name)s`

```
\textbf{\Large "%(homework_title)s" \\}
\vspace{1cm}
\textbf{\Large "%(course_name)s" \\}
```

Then, from Python, you can load in that template and format it as:

```
template = file('template.tex', 'r').read()
page = template % {'course_name' : 'Computer Science 500', 
                   'homework_title' : 'NP-Complete'}
file('result.tex', 'w').write(page)
```

If you want to find those tokens automatically, the following should do pretty well:

```
import sys
import re
import subprocess

template = file('template.tex', 'r').read()
pattern = re.compile('%\(([^}]+)\)[bcdeEfFgGnosxX%]')
tokens = pattern.findall(template)

token_values = dict()
for token in tokens:
    sys.stdout.write('Enter value for ' + token + ': ')
    token_values[token] = sys.stdin.readline().strip()

page = template % token_values
file('result.tex', 'w').write(page)

subprocess.call('pdflatex result.tex')
```

The code will iterate across the tokens and print a prompt to the console asking you for an input for each token.  In the above example, you'll get two prompts (with example answers):

```
Enter value for homework_title: NP-Complete
Enter value for course_name: Computer Science 500
```

The final line calls `pdflatex` on the resulting file and generates a PDF from it.  If you want to go further, you could also ask the user for an output file name or take it as an command line option.

Comment: I needed to add `shell=True` to subprocess call.

Comment: Since we like overkill, I want to see the Jinja answer!

Answer (score 5):

There is also a [Template](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/string.html#template-strings) class (since 2.4) allowing to use `$that` token instead of `%(thi)s` one.

Answer (score 5):

There's a Python library exactly for that: [PyLaTeX](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/). The following code was [taken directly from the documentation](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/examples/basic.html):

```
from pylatex import Document, Section, Subsection, Command
from pylatex.utils import italic, NoEscape


def fill_document(doc):
    """Add a section, a subsection and some text to the document.

    :param doc: the document
    :type doc: :class:`pylatex.document.Document` instance
    """
    with doc.create(Section('A section')):
        doc.append('Some regular text and some ')
        doc.append(italic('italic text. '))

        with doc.create(Subsection('A subsection')):
            doc.append('Also some crazy characters: $&#{}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Basic document
    doc = Document('basic')
    fill_document(doc)

    doc.generate_pdf(clean_tex=False)
    doc.generate_tex()

    # Document with `\maketitle` command activated
    doc = Document()

    doc.preamble.append(Command('title', 'Awesome Title'))
    doc.preamble.append(Command('author', 'Anonymous author'))
    doc.preamble.append(Command('date', NoEscape(r'\today')))
    doc.append(NoEscape(r'\maketitle'))

    fill_document(doc)

    doc.generate_pdf('basic_maketitle', clean_tex=False)

    # Add stuff to the document
    with doc.create(Section('A second section')):
        doc.append('Some text.')

    doc.generate_pdf('basic_maketitle2', clean_tex=False)
    tex = doc.dumps()  # The document as string in LaTeX syntax
```

It's particularly useful for generating automatic reports or slides.

Comment: Be aware that things like ```generate_pdf``` need to have ```pdflatex``` or similar installed (which in turn deppend on **Perl** I think?). I ended up using ```PyLaTeX``` at  ```PythonAnywhere```, since it's free and it has all this working almost by default.