# ValueError: unsupported format character '

Tags: python

I got most of the following code from here: [Generating pdf-latex with python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085520/generating-pdf-latex-with-python-script)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import division
from functions import *
import shlex

#from Utilities import *
import os
import argparse
import subprocess

equation = '\begin{equation*}1 + \gamma\lambda B/2\end{equation*}'

content=r'''\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent\rotatebox{180}{\vbox{%
    %(equation)s
    }%
}
\end{document}
'''

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-e', '--equation', default=equation)

args=parser.parse_args()
content%args.__dict__

print content%args.__dict__
```

running this code gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "latex.py", line 29, in <module>
    content%args.__dict__
ValueError: unsupported format character '
' (0xa) at index 104
```

anybody know what's going wrong?  I've got the same error from other methods of rotating the page.

Comment: It is telling you that that it doesn't support linefeeds.

Comment: *Aside*: the string literal for `equation` should probably be a raw string literal: `equation = r'\begin ...'`.

Comment: @AronVietti: It is telling you that `%\n` is not a valid formatting syntax.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*Any* `%` in `content` is seen as a formatting placeholder. Double any that are not a placeholder:

```
content=r'''\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent\rotatebox{180}{\vbox{%%
    %(equation)s
    }%%
}
\end{document}
'''
```

Otherwise the `%` at the end of the `\noindent\rotatebox{180}{\vbox{%` line is seen together with the `\n` newline as a formatting character, hence the exception with an embedded newline.

Comment: Hit this error while encoding a calculation that used modulus as a string.