# subprocess.Popen(cmd) does not find command that can be run in Terminal

Tags: macos, python-3.x, tex

For the context: I am on macOS, developing with Spyder. I installed TeX with MACTeX.

I am working on creating an automatic text document and I like to use the solution proposed here: [Generating pdf-latex with python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085520/generating-pdf-latex-with-python-script)

When excecuting the python script in Spyder, I hang on the line calling "subprocess.Popen(cmd)". The error is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pdflatex'"
```

If I try to execute the command `pdflatex` in Terminal, it finds the command and executes it flawlessly.

I probably have a path missing or something similar, though I am puzzled my the error message as it mentions as missing file and I would expect a missing command.

Comment: Try  `subprocess.Popen(['pdflatex'], shell=True)`.

Comment: This does the trick, thanks Mike !

Comment: Great. Made it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `shell=True` to get the right shell settings:

```
subprocess.Popen(['pdflatex'], shell=True)
```

Comment: Ok, I went from error to error :D. The first I got when using the solution is an error 127 (command not found) that I solved giving the command full path "/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex" that is found with the command "which pdflatex" in Terminal. I now face error 1... still digging.

Comment: Ok, I went to the end of it. One of my issues is that I had is that I used tcsh as the default shell on macOS. I changed it to bash (which is normal for current OSX versions). Now using the full path to call pdflatex as indicated above executes fine with no errors.