# Can you use Python to output mathematical expressions onto MS Word, PDF or HTML files?

Tags: python, math, symbolic-math

I specifically mean mathematical expressions like square root symbols, fractions, exponents, etc.

I have no problem teaching myself the syntax in whatever language is needed to write those symbols. But I'm completely lost on where to begin. Can someone provide an example of a file that converts the quadratic formula to something that can be made into a .docx, .pdf or .html file? Like, what Python libraries would be required to accomplish this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating pdf-latex with python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085520/generating-pdf-latex-with-python-script)

Comment: Maybe take a look at Sympy and see what kind of LaTeX or other output is possible there.

Comment: Random Davis, I tried to run the file they gave, and it had a file cannot be found error on the line: proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd) I'm not sure if that's out of my control. Robert Dodier, do you have a good youtube video recommendation? A lot of the results are about how to use sympy, when I just want to get to the part about creating files.

Comment: K J Yeah, in my research yesterday and today, I understand how to display MathML from an HTML file, so that partially answers my question. But how exactly would I do the same for MS Word and PDFs?

Comment: This was the specific file not found error:
  proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: K J, thanks, good to know!