# How to hide the Miktex prompt when making a pdf from app?

Tags: python, latex, miktex

I created an app that makes a report pdf from a latex code. I got the code from here [Generating pdf-latex with python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085520/generating-pdf-latex-with-python-script). The works great, but when I run the app and make the PDF it also opens a prompt before making the report. Is there a way I can hide the prompt, something I can change in the code from this post to hide the prompmt?.

See below for what pops up:

[image]

Thank u in advance